# ReactJS maximum update depth exceeded error when using MUI TabPanel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I am still having difficulty to see what is causing the error. I have this component with useEffect:

```
const MyTestComponent = (): JSX.Element => {

const classes = useStyles();
const { someRouteId } = useParams<Params>();
const { exampleDispatch, exampleState } = useContext(ExampleContext);
const [testData, setTestData] = useState<GroupSummary[]>(exampleState.exampleData);
const [index, setIndex] = useState(pageSize);

useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedExampleData(parseInt(someRouteId));
}, [someRouteId]);

const setSelectedExampleData = (id: number): void => {
  exampleDispatch({
    type: ExampleActionTypes.SetSelectedExampleData,
    data: exampleState.exampleData.find(x => x.ID === id)!,
  });
};

return (
  <>
    {testData?.length > 0 && (
          testData.map(x=> (
            <div key={`${x.ID}`}>
              <SomeOtherComponent testData={x} setSelectedExampleData ={setSelectedExampleData} />
            </div>
          ))
    )}
    {<Button handleClick={seeMore} text="See More" />}
  </>
);
};

export default MyTestComponent;
```

If I use the component like this, by itself, I don't get the maximum depth exceeded error. However, I have another component with tabs where on one of the tabs, I want to show this component. This is the code I have used for that:

```
        <Tabs
          value={selectedTabValue}
          onChange={handleChangeTab}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="fullWidth"
      >
        {tabs.map((item) => (
          <Tab
            label={item.label}
            key={item.label}
            disableRipple
            disableTouchRipple
          />
        ))}
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={selectedTabValue} index={0}>
        <MyTestComponent/>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={selectedTabValue} index={1}>
        <SomeOtherTestComponent/>
      </TabPanel>
```

This is the code for the TabPanel:

```
  const handleChangeTab = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number): void => {
    setSelectedTabValue(newValue);
  };

  const TabPanel = (props: TabPanelProps): JSX.Element => {
    const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

    return (
      <div
        role="tabpanel"
        hidden={value !== index}
        id={`tabpanel-${index}`}
        aria-labelledby={`tab-${index}`}
        {...other}
      >
        {value === index && (
          <Typography component="span">
            {children}
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

When I use it like this, the useEffect in the MyTestComponent causes the error. Does anyone can see what the problem could be and how to fix this? Thank you in advance.